# Selenium not finding element on first attempt

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrap a [website](https://www.ossiam.com/EN/) using Selenium and Python. My code is below:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://www.ossiam.com/EN/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'label[class="btn btn-outline-success ls0 nott"]').click()
```

But as I execute it first time, i get the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"label[class="btn btn-outline-success ls0 nott"]"}
```

But when I run this part again manually as I am running this code in spyder:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'label[class="btn btn-outline-success ls0 nott"]').click()
```

The code is working fine without any errors.

Can someone please help me understand what could be the problem here?

Comment: Perhaps the DOM is not fully loaded and the element can't be found. You could use a `Wait` to wait for the element to be present. [selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: I did use wait, still getting the same error. I used sleep, implicit_wait but still getting the same error. Explicit_wait is also giving me Timeout error.

Comment: you can put `time.sleep(5)` before `find_element(...)`